# How to generate a list of daily changes to my notes?

Tags: diff, file-comparison, meld

**Background**:
I use [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/) to organize my notes as I study. It's an application which works "on top of" a collection of markdown formatted plain text files and then shows the links and connections between them graphically. The text files I stored within sub folders of a single folder

**What I want:**
Since I am studying for an upcoming exam, I add information to several of these text files each day. At the end of the day, I'd like to have an automatically generated single text file containing all the changes I made to each of my files. A kind of "daily digest" which I can then read through to revise everything I learned on that day.

**Additional background:**
I already have a cron job set up to use rsync to make an uncompressed copy of my notes folder every day at 3:00 AM. I assume this copy can act as a reference when I want to see what modifications have been made at the end of the current day.

**An example**
Let's say on the 15th of May, I made the following changes
Added "`This is some new text`" to file A
Added - "`this is some more textual information`" to file B.

My "daily digest" at the end of the 15th of May would read

```
"This is some new text"
This is some more textual information"
```

**My Research:**
I understand that tools like diff and meld (GUI) are great for comparing files.
The diff output formatting it a quite difficult to understand. Meld on the other hand is very easy to use but it's a GUI app so I can't figure out how to direct it's output to a single text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is literally a *version control system* that you're building there :)

Luckily, that is a problem that's already been solved. One of such tools is `git` (it's quite certainly also the most proliferate tool in that discipline).

I don't know obsidian, but assuming it doesn't even already come with some integration for `git`:

0. At the very beginning, and only once, you go into the directory containing your .md files and initialize the current directory as git *repository*, using `git init .`

   0.1. The Internet<sup>TM</sup> says Obsidian puts its configuration in that same directory in a subdirectory called `.obsidian`. We want to ignore that, so we put a text file called `.gitignore` next to it, with only one line of content:

```
.obsidian/
```

1. We bring any new files (and at this point, *all* your markdown files are new) to git's attention: `git add file1.md file2.md …` (Or just `git add *.md`)
2. we say, OK, note the current state of these added files in the index: `git commit -m "This is the initial state"`
3. Congratulations! We just made our first git commit! Run `git log -p` to see what changes that involved. Since we went from "nothing" to "files with content", we see a log with a patch set that starts with all `+` for added lines.
4. Now we change some file. Say, we change the third line in `file3.md`. We save, and `git commit -m "End of day commit" file3.md`. (If we instead made a *new* file, we need to `git add filename.md` that first!).
5. Check `git log -p`'s output: You will see something like

```
@ 3,3
- old line content
+ new line content
```

More complex changes work the same – you get a `diff` representation highlighting what has changed between commits. Git can do much, much more, but explaining that would leave the scope of this question.

There's many many many tools to make dealing with git logs more graphical or generally prettier. I use `tig` a lot, for example.

So, instead of your 3am rsync job, an appropriate `git add *.md; git commit -sm "Automatic end of day commit"` would make tracking your changes trivial. For backup purposes, you just `git push` (again, this leads too far, I'm just mentioning it because you said you were copying things via `rsync`, and I was assuming that was for backup purposes).

Comment: Thank you, Sir! 
I have heard of Git and even used it a bit. It never occurred to me that it was what I needed for this use case. 
Thanks! I'll try it.

Comment: I followed your advice and created a git repository for my notes. However, I can't find a got command to show me all the daily changes

Comment: as said, `git log -p` will give you a scrollable list, no? In as far does that not do what you want?

Comment: It does but it seems to give the log for all commits. I'll have a look at the documentation. Thank you!

Comment: The changes are displayed grouped by commit.